# Finding most time consuming stored procedures in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

is there any way (apart from SQL profiler) to find the list of stored procedures in SQL 2005/2008 (without executing them) that are most time consuming ?
 The reason I need this is to specifically target those stored procedures to be used for optimization. 
 Thanks.

Comment: you could try googling that yourself: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=sql+server+most+expensive+queries&safe=off

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem, if you require information on procedure execution, worker time, physical and logical reads and writes or procedure elapsed time. You can select this data from 
sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats this returns all the above data however the procedure are displayed by their database object id.

If you use the following script below this will return the procedure in a more readable format by linking the stats to the sys.object table we are able to retrieve the procedure names. The script must be run against the database in which the procedures are stored.

```
Select name, type, type_desc, create_date, modify_date, cached_time, last_execution_time, execution_count, total_worker_time, last_worker_time, min_worker_time, max_worker_time, total_physical_reads, last_physical_reads, min_physical_reads, max_physical_reads, total_logical_writes, last_logical_writes, min_logical_writes, max_logical_writes, total_logical_reads, last_logical_reads, min_logical_reads, max_logical_reads, total_elapsed_time, last_elapsed_time, min_elapsed_time, max_elapsed_timefrom sys.objects obj Join sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats stat ON obj.object_id = stat.object_id where obj.type = 'P'
```

You can find the worst performing procedures by filtering the results. In the company I work for we generally use the last elapsed time, execution count and min worker time to find the procedures for optimisation.